# creating a form with many rows and columns with bootstrap

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a django template which i want it to present a model form but with different columns and rows. More specifically i want them to be in lets say a grid of three columns and the last row will have the remaining if any. My template is rendering  (its a bit large so i used fiddle)[the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/zEcW5/). But while i see the different rows, my form stil has one column. Am i missing something?

(Must I enter the code here too?)

```
<div id="personal-data">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/customer/edit/1/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" value="KTN76otstgqNoyE7Whzn6L9TAC2jvR9u" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"></input>
        <legend> Name </legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_first_name">

                        First name

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-first_name">
                        <input id="id_first_name" class="form-control" type="text" value="Name" name="first_name" maxlength="150"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_last_name">

                        Last name

                    </label>   
                    <div id="form-last_name">
                        <input id="id_last_name" class="form-control" type="text" value="Name" name="last_name" maxlength="200"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_email">

                        Email

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-email">
                        <input id="id_email" class="form-control" type="text" name="email" maxlength="200"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_telephone">

                        Telephone

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-telephone">
                        <input id="id_telephone" class="form-control" type="text" value="(664) 654-6545" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" name="telephone" maxlength="14" autocomplete="off"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_mobile">

                        Mobile

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-mobile">
                        <input id="id_mobile" class="form-control" type="text" value="9999999999" name="mobile" maxlength="25"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_street">

                        Street

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-street">
                        <input id="id_street" class="form-control" type="text" name="street" maxlength="255"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_region">

                        Region

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-region">
                        <input id="id_region" class="form-control" type="text" name="region" maxlength="130"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_state">

                        State

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-state">
                        <input id="id_state" class="form-control" type="text" name="state" maxlength="70"></input>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_city">

                        City

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-city">
                        <input id="id_city" class="form-control" type="text" name="city" maxlength="120"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_neighbourhood">

                        Neighbourhood

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-neighbourhood">
                        <input id="id_neighbourhood" class="form-control" type="text" name="neighbourhood" maxlength="160"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_postal_code">

                        Postal code

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-postal_code">
                        <input id="id_postal_code" class="form-control" type="text" name="postal_code" maxlength="20"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_country">

                        Country

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-country">
                        <input id="id_country" class="form-control" type="text" name="country" maxlength="100"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_file">

                        Picture

                    </label>
                    <div id="form-file">


                          Currently: 

                    <a href="/media/pictures/picture_1.jpg"> … </a>
                    <input id="file-clear_id" type="checkbox" name="file-clear"></input>
                        <label for="file-clear_id">

                            Clear

                        </label>
                        <br></br>

                        Change: 

                        <input id="id_file" type="file" name="file"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn form-control" type="submit"> … </button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

I didn't want to put such large code here, but it said that if I add a fiddler link it needs code too.

EDIT: I'm sorry forgot to mention that the form is wrapped in a div with class .container. If I change the form class to .form-inline I still don't get the result I want but my form seem to get out of the "container's" bounds

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle doesn't include Bootstrap..

You can use Bootply instead (it includes Bootstrap and jQuery): http://bootply.com/89310

Also, your HTML markup is a little off...

HTML input should be closed like..

```
<input id="id_country" class="form-control" type="text" name="country" maxlength="100"/>
```

Not this..

```
<input id="id_country" class="form-control" type="text" name="country" maxlength="100"></input>
```

Comment: I didn't know how to include it in fiddle...i'm sorry for that. I know about the </input> but this is how django renders the fields of a model form. But I tried similar code to aptana and an html file and worked....Copy pasted it.

Comment: This happens when you are a given a code that's not yours. Apparently the previous owner used bootstrap >3 so it didn't work :)...Works now like a charm. Ty all!